# show $\int_{\partial U}\frac{f}{z-p}dz-\int\int\overline{\partial}fd\overline{z}\wedge dz=0$ for $p \notin cl(U)$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I'm asked to verify;
$0=\int_{\partial U}\frac{f}{z-p}dz+\int\int_{U}\frac{\overline{\partial}f}{z-p}dz\wedge d\overline{z}$

Where $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ is open, bounded and has a smooth boundary, $p \notin cl(U)$ and $f \in C^1$, $f:cl(U)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

My attempt;

Define $\alpha=\frac{f}{z-p}dz$. Then by Green we have $$\int_{\partial U}\frac{f}{z-p}dz=\int\int_{U}d(\frac{f}{z-p})dz=\int\int_U \overline{\partial}f(\frac{1}{z-p})+f\overline{\partial}\frac{1}{z-p}d\overline{z} \wedge dz$$
$$=\int\int_{U}\frac{\overline{\partial}f}{z-p}d\overline{z}\wedge dz$$

And the identity follows by subtraction.  My main concern is that I don't see why it was critical that $p \notin cl(U)$ (other than that would merely lead to the Cauchy–Pompieu with $2\pi if(p)$ on the LHS.

Comment: It is a requirement for Green’s theorem that the 1-form is defined on all of $U$. As an example take $U$ the unit disc, $p=0$ and $f=1$.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand, f is defined on all of $U$, and I get no problems at z=p since p is not in $U$.

Comment: Nevermind. I think your comment is addressing my concern at the end, not the validity of my proof/calculation? Please do confirm though.

Comment: Yes, my comment is about the requirement that $p \not \in \overline U$.